# How does one export Minecraft "Better Together" to Remix 3D?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Recently, [Remix 3D welcomed Minecraft creators](https://blog.remix3d.com/en/2017/09/welcoming-minecraft-to-remix-3d/) to their site.  The welcome blog post starts in the middle:

> So, you’ve found yourself here and you’ve exported a Minecraft structure.

Wait.  How do I actually export a Minecraft structure?  I don't see an export option in any of the in-game menus or commands on the edition I'm using (Windows 10 edition, "Better Together" update v1.2.0).

Which versions/editions of Minecraft have added this new export capability, and how does one actually cause the export to happen from the game?

Please post a screenshot of the game's UI doing this if you can (even if it's not the same edition that I have, I'm curious to see how the game's UI works for this).  Thanks!

Comment: I have no experience with minecraft other than the java edition, but in the java edition, there is a block called "structure block", which saves the blocks within a user defined area to the harddrive as a file. could that be the sort of structure that you're looking for?

Comment: The next sentence on that page is: "Why don’t you try sharing your creation on Facebook, Twitter, Tumblr or your favourite social media channel?" I think that means that the export isn't a step in Minecraft in preparation to getting it into Remix3D, but rather the last step in Remix3D to save it to a file. Is this meant to be a 3D printing program for Minecraft structures? Or could it maybe just be a 3D painting program that contains Minecraft textures amongst others?

Comment: I'm not looking for the social media side as much, I'm trying to figure out if Minecraft can really export to GLTF (*.glb) format or any 3D model file format.  I know that Remix3D stuff can be downloaded into Paint3D and then saved to a variety of 3D formats, which makes it a possibility.  I'm interested in any sort of in-game partial-world export capability, and how it is accessed.  The "structure block" sounds very interesting, but I don't see that in the Win10 edition.

Comment: @emackey In that case, the structure block is not what you are looking for. The resulting file doesn't contain vertex data and such... It's basically just a list of all the blocks in an area, saved in such way that the structure can be copied into any minecraft world.

Comment: Actually, looks like structure blocks are exactly it!  In the Win 10 edition at least, saving a section of your world from a structure block does indeed create a *.glb file, which can be loaded in ThreeJS, BabylonJS, and can even be previewed in 3D on OneDrive's online viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out! It does indeed use Structure Blocks. You must use the /give command to get one, switch to creative mode, place it, activate it, and then you can set coordinates. The structure block only works as an export mechanism, but there's a nice UI with a preview to see exactly what you'll get, and then it exports a GLB file that can be viewed.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else trying to export 3D models of their Minecraft world, this is what I know now:

- In January 2020, "Remix 3D" will be shut down, and as of now the option to upload from Minecraft to Remix 3D is gone from the game.  This shutdown has not hampered the ability to export to a file locally.
- The option to export 3D models to `*.glb` files ([glTF 2.0 format](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF)) exists in the Windows 10 edition, but does not appear available in the Java or mobile versions.
- You need to be in a "Creative" mode game with "Operator" status (the gold crown icon in the player list).
- In that game, the command is `/give @s structure_block`.  The `@s` means "self" and can be substituted with any player name.  The player will need a free slot in their hotbar to receive the structure block.
- Place the Structure Block into the Minecraft world, and right-click to active it.  This opens a UI for choosing a nearby area to export, up to 32 x 32 x 32 in size.
- Fill out the blank name field, and adjust the size & offsets to taste, then click the Export button to produce the GLB file.

The resulting file can then be loaded or imported into most applications that load glTF, including Blender 2.80.